# How to pass large json result from ansible play into python script

Tags: python, json, ansible

I get an 'Argument list too long' error when passing very large json result to python script from within an Ansible playbook.

The base playbook is:

```
- name: "The Playbook"
  hosts: "localhost"

  tasks:
    - name: "Get JSON from API"
      uri:
        url: "https://my.real.api.url.goes.here.com"
        method: GET
        return_content: yes
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "my api token goes here and works."
      register: result

    - name: Run Py script
      command: python get_tenants.py {{ result }}
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      register: pyout
```

I've also tried passing the result as:

```
{{ result | map(attribute='content') }}
```

which passes a pointer to a map but not the map itself as a single item.

I've also tried passing the result as:

```
{{ result | map(attribute='content') | list }}
```

Regardless, I get:

```
"failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 7] Argument list too long", "rc": 7
```

How would I go about passing a large JSON result from ansible into a python script?

The first idea I had was to save the results to file and then use the file within the python script. It seems to me, however, that there has to be a better way...

Comment: If you're using Ansible 2.4+, maybe try passing it to the script via stdin instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a [here document](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) if your script is able to read input from STDIN:

```
- name: "The Playbook"
  hosts: "localhost"

  tasks:
    - name: "Get JSON from API"
      uri:
        url: "https://my.real.api.url.goes.here.com"
        method: GET
        return_content: yes
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "my api token goes here and works."
      register: result

    - name: Run Py script
      shell: |
        python get_tenants.py <<EOF
        "{{ result.content }}"
        EOF
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      register: pyout
```